# Could The Mark of The Beast simply be what a Man is made of?

Tags: revelation, isaiah, 1-thessalonians

There's something I've been studying up on and was curious what this community might have to say about it.

According to Revelation 13:18 the number of The Beast is 666 and when looking into certain verses such as Isaiah 30:33 it brought me to Chemistry. And to my Surprise The Carbon Atom which Man is made from (Man being a Carbon based lifeform) was made up of 6 protons, 6 electrons, and 6 neutrons, 666.

Could The Mark of Man (The Beast) simply be the fact that one is an Unregenerated Man of The World? And not some Computer Chip or anything one has to take willingly.

But as for those who are saved and in Christ, they would be regenerated into The Glorified Body during the events that take place in 1 Thessalonians 4:17.

When looking at everything Man is made up of oxygen, carbon, hydrogen, nitrogen, calcium, phosphorus etc: I counted that there is a combined total of 397 protons, electrons and neutrons. Just 3 shy of 400 which under The Bible symbolizes "a divinely perfect period"

Could it be That God with all His knowledge adds something extra to The Human Body, that Extra 3 needed to make the 400 in order to bring us to a Christ like Glorified Body?

Comment: No - such a suggestion is unbiblical.

Comment: The 'mark' is quite clearly a matter of visionary allusion. Much of what John saw is imaginative ; depicting truth in vivid, pictorial narrative as a means of conveying spiritualities in memorable terms. It is a great mistake to assume such things are physical and visible in the material world. In any case, you forgot to add iron which is  an essential component to convey oxygen in haemoglobin, and selenium (essential for thyroid function) so that mucks up your figures.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up the number and the mark of the beast.

Answer (score 2):

According to Revelation 1:1, the purpose of the Revelation was to show God's servants what was about to happen:

> [Rev 1:1 NLT] (1) This is a revelation from Jesus Christ, which God gave him to show his servants the events that must soon take place. He sent an angel to present this revelation to his servant John,

It would not be possible for the assemblies in Laodicea and Pergamum to understand such a deeply encoded message. So it would be as stupid as sending a message in Farsi or Swahili to people in those locales as sending a message based on genetic code. Actually it would be worse. And Paul rebukes such a practice:

> [1Co 14:6, 19, 23 NLT] (6) Dear brothers and sisters, if I should come to you speaking in an unknown language, how would that help you? But if I bring you a revelation or some special knowledge or prophecy or teaching, that will be helpful. ... (19) But in a church meeting I would rather speak five understandable words to help others than ten thousand words in an unknown language. ... (23) Even so, if unbelievers or people who don't understand these things come into your church meeting and hear everyone speaking in an unknown language, they will think you are crazy.

So on that basis I think we should dismiss out of hand (with prejudice) any notion of a meaning of any part of the Revelation that would not be immediately apparent to his hearers.

> [1Co 14:11 KJV] (11) Therefore if I know not the meaning of the voice, I shall be unto him that speaketh a barbarian, and he that speaketh shall be a barbarian unto me.

A much better approach is to see that the things that are about to happen refers to the impending destruction of the temple. Revelation is the tale of the Old being judged and destroyed and the New being established. The Old is the earthly Jerusalem temple-based theocracy and the New is the new covenant resurrected Israel of God described in Ezekiel 37:

https://www.blueletterbible.org/nlt/eze/37/1/s_839001

Please see my answer to a related question here:

https://www.quora.com/What-is-Matthew-25-in-the-Bible/answer/Bill-Ross-22

Thank you, sir, and so nice to meet you. Namaste.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that 6 is short of perfection. Shy of 7. 'We' were made on the 6th day, and made 'incomplete,' in the sense that **Jehovah God planted a garden in Eden, in the east; and there He put the man whom He had formed. And out of the ground Jehovah God caused to grow every tree that is pleasant to the sight and good for food, as well as the tree of life...And Jehovah God commanded the man, saying, Of every tree of the garden you may eat...** Gen 2. So even the 'best' man is incomplete, without **Christ who is our life** Col 3.

Then, 'simultaneous' with being incomplete, man fell. Sinned. Became fallen. Sinful. **Through one man sin entered into the world, and through sin, death; and thus death passed on to all men...Through the disobedience of one man the many were constituted sinners** Rm 5. Mingled with sin. But there's good news to help on both of these counts, and on the count too of the guilt of sin.

**Could The Mark of Man (The Beast) simply be the fact that one is an Unregenerated Man of The World? And not some Computer Chip or anything one has to take willingly.** 666 seems to indicate unregenerate man...to the max. But it is the number of a specific man, Caesar Nero, per both the Greek and Hebrew letter-values of that title/name. And so, like with the second man/last Adam (1 Cor 15:45-49), the folks who have the beast's name, choose to take it (even if under duress, Rv 13:16-17; 14:9-11).

Answer (score 1):

Peace.

Interesting observation of the carbon atom of man. I did not know that.

I have had several different theories about 666 before…but here is another theory to present.

666 =  the sum of Greek letters:  **chi xi stigma**

χξϛ chx stigma, the 22nd, 14th and an obsolete letter (G4742 as a cross) of the Greek alphabet (intermediate between the 5th and 6th).

The Greek letters are symbols of:

**Chi = Christ
Xi = cross
Stigma = puncture, pierce, a mark from a pointed instrument, often as a sign of ownership.**

As we know, Jesus was “numbered” with the transgressors in the place “Golgotha”…which means the place of the skull (cranium).

> Mark 15:22 KJV (22)  *And they bring him unto **the place Golgotha, which
>   is, being interpreted, The place of a skull**.*

Today, this numbering/reckoning/estimation is still going on inside the MINDs of many…the mind which is located in the place of the skull or cranium.

Jesus is still being numbered with the transgressors…those who are currently preaching “another Jesus” in the wisdom of man and preaching another gospel for money’s sake (the “thieves” surround Him).

> Mark 15:27-28 KJV (27)  *And with him they crucify two thieves; the one
>   on his right hand, and the other on his left. (28)  And the scripture
>   was fulfilled, which saith, **And he was numbered with the
>   transgressors.***

When we choose the preaching of the wisdom of man to listen to, then the cross of Christ is made none effect.

The “stigma” is the piercing of the power of the cross in our lives…the making it of “none effect”….to neutralize, to be empty.    Without this power in our lives, we perish without the receiving of His eternal life in this mortal body.

> 1 Corinthians 1:17-20 KJV (17)  *For Christ sent me not to baptize, but
>   to preach the gospel: **not with wisdom of words, lest the cross of
>   Christ should be made of none effect**. (18)  For the preaching of the
>   cross is **to them that perish** foolishness; but unto us which are saved
>   it is the power of God. (19)  For it is written, **I will destroy the
>   wisdom of the wise, and will bring to nothing the understanding of the
>   prudent.** (20)  Where is the wise? where is the scribe? where is the
>   disputer of this world? hath not God made foolish the wisdom of this
>   world?*

The “assembly of the wicked”…the assembly of Satan…have pierced His “hands”…that is, His power.  Hands = power.   The power of the cross of Christ is being neutralized in our own lives when we listen to the “thieves”  and submit to their things…their authority. We don not then walk in the Way that leads to His eternal life.

> Psalms 22:16 KJV (16)  *For dogs have compassed me: the assembly of the
>   wicked have inclosed me: **they pierced my hands and my feet**.*

Here is wisdom…..man’s wisdom.  Let him that has “understanding”….that is, the mind which is inside the cranium…..count (vote with well-worn pebbles as a verdict) the number of the beast.

It is the number of man….it is a census taken.    Mankind always takes a census.

“Polls” …which means “skulls”…were counted in the census of Numbers 1.  The renowned….the princes….the heads were to help do the census.

> Numbers 1:16-18 KJV (16)  *These were the renowned of the congregation,
>   princes of the tribes of their fathers, heads of thousands in Israel.*

Interestingly, “expressed” = puncture.

> (17)  And Moses and Aaron took these men which **are expressed by their
>   names**:

“polls” = skulls

> (18)  *And they assembled all the congregation together on the first
>   day of the second month, and they declared their pedigrees after their
>   families, by the house of their fathers, according to the number of
>   the names, from twenty years old and upward, **by their polls**.*

666 = the census count of the transgressors who are preaching “another Jesus” and “another gospel” and which many decide to go and listen to and join  them where the power of the cross of Christ is being pierced.

This is the census of the “synagogue”….that is, gathering…of Satan that is piercing the power of the cross out of the lives of many by the “name” or authority of the beast .

Again, men…in their own  professed “wise” minds…are voting/deciding for man’s wisdom who are preaching “another Jesus” and another gospel and who are wresting the Scriptures to their own destruction.   They are taking their listeners along with them.

Many are reckoning in their own mind that the real Jesus Christ (Chi Xi) is with the transgressors (in the 666 group of people who are preaching “another Jesus”) and they listen to them.   But what is happening in this group is the power to neutralize (to pierce) the power of the cross of the true Christ.  the number of his name...or authority to do this.

> Revelation 13:18 KJV (18)  **Here is wisdom. Let him that hath
>   understanding count the number of the beast: for it is the number of a
>   man; and his number is Six hundred threescore and six.**

Interestingly, the number of the children of “Adonikam”….meaning “the lord of the enemies or the lord of rising” (the 1st beast that arises from sea)….is 666 and speaks of “another Jesus” (the 1st beast) being preached.

The “lord of the enemies”  is “another” Jesus being preached as they suppose/reckon in the mind that the real Jesus is among the census 666 group of transgressors.   The “lord of the enemies” is their “another Jesus” that they follow and not the real Jesus who is the real Christ.

> Ezra 2:13 KJV (13)  **The children of Adonikam, six hundred sixty and
>   six.**

Greater is He (the real Jesus Christ within you) that is in you than “he” (another jesus….the lord of the enemies of the cross of Christ) that is in the world (the 666 group).

We are to overcome them (the number of the beast…..the 666 group that are worshipping “another Jesus”).  They are of the world…the religious orderly arrangements we call “churches”.

> 1 John 4:4-6 KJV (4)  Ye are of God, little children, **and have
>   overcome them: because greater is he that is in you, than he that is
>   in the world.**

They are of the world….the 666 group….and their own kind listen only to them.

> (5)  *T**hey are of the world: therefore speak they of the world, and the
>   world heareth them.** (6)  We are of God: he that knoweth God heareth
>   us; he that is not of God heareth not us. Hereby know we the spirit of
>   truth, and the spirit of error.*

They are in bondage to the 666 group as they are one with them and only listen to them.   They have gone into “captivity” into the 666 group…into the gathering of Satan.

> Revelation 13:10 KJV (10)  ***He that leadeth into captivity shall go
>   into captivity:*** he that killeth with the sword must be killed with the
>   sword. Here is the patience and the faith of the saints.

And the end of the transgressors (all 666 together) is destruction.

> Isaiah 1:27-28 KJV (27)  *Zion shall be redeemed with judgment, and her
>   converts with righteousness. (28)  **And the destruction of the
>   transgressors and of the sinners shall be together,** and they that
>   forsake the LORD shall be consumed.*

The “enemies of the cross of Christ” are in the 666 group of people.   They have pierced the power of the cross out of their own lives.  Their end is destruction.  They mind earthly things….and we know that Satan only minds the things of man and not the things of God.

> Philippians 3:18-19 KJV (18)  *(For many walk, of whom I have told you
>   often, and now tell you even weeping, **that they are the enemies of the
>   cross of Christ: (19)  Whose end is destruction,** whose God is their
>   belly, and whose glory is in their shame, who mind earthly things.)*

Here is wisdom. …seeing ourselves as “wise”, we suffer fools gladly and let a man bring us into their bondage…into the 666 group… where they devour us and take from us and they exalt themselves and smite us on the face.

> 2 Corinthians 11:19-20 KJV (19)  *For ye suffer fools gladly, s**eeing ye
>   yourselves are wise.** (20)  For ye suffer, if a man bring you into
>   bondage, if a man devour you, if a man take of you, if a man exalt
>   himself, if a man smite you on the face.*

We also share in their mortal destruction from off this earth when we think that Jesus …the real Jesus Christ…is being preached among them who are not holding the Head of Christ where the true Mind is.

> Colossians 2:19-23 KJV (19)  *And not holding the Head, from which all
>   the body by joints and bands having nourishment ministered, and knit
>   together, increaseth with the increase of God. (20)  Wherefore if ye
>   be dead with Christ from the rudiments of the world, why, as though
>   living in the world, are ye subject to ordinances, (21)  (Touch not;
>   taste not; handle not; (22)  **Which all are to perish with the using;)
>   after the commandments and doctrines of men**?*

Here is wisdom….we see ourselves as “wise” and  decide to go to a “church” and live according to their doctrines and commandments of men and be in bondage to them.

Yet, it is “will worship” as we worship our own “wisdom”  as we see it is wise to do and keep their carnal commandments.   It seems to be prudent and wise to ourselves to do them…but in the end we perish with the using up of them.

> (23)  *W**hich things have indeed a shew of wisdom in will worship,** and
>   humility, and neglecting of the body; not in any honour to the
>   satisfying of the flesh.*

There is a way that seems right unto a man, but the end of it are the ways of death (their end is destruction).

> Proverbs 14:12 KJV (12)  **There is a way which seemeth right unto a
>   man, but the end thereof are the ways of death.**

The keeping of the handwriting of church ordinances ( ordinance =“dogma” = “what one thinks is right”) is against us.  The keeping of church handwritings (the church scribes’ documents of their  carnal commands) lead to death.  They do nothing to save our mortal flesh.  They once had the power to neutralize the cross of Christ of its power but will fail as the Lord triumphs over them.

> Colossians 2:13-15 KJV (13)  *And you, being dead in your sins and the
>   uncircumcision of your flesh, hath he quickened together with him,
>   having forgiven you all trespasses; (14)  **Blotting out the handwriting
>   of ordinances that was against us, which was contrary to us, and took
>   it out of the way, nailing it to his cross; (15)  And having spoiled
>   principalities and powers,** he made a shew of them openly, triumphing
>   over them in it.*

We must come out from among them (the 666 group) and be separate.   We must overcome the number of his “name”….his authority to neutralize the power of the cross of Christ.

> 2 Corinthians 6:14-18 KJV (14)  Be ye not unequally yoked together
>   with unbelievers: for what fellowship hath righteousness with
>   unrighteousness? and what communion hath light with darkness? (15) 
>   And what concord hath Christ with Belial? or what part hath he that
>   believeth with an infidel? (16)  And what agreement hath the temple of
>   God with idols? for ye are the temple of the living God; as God hath
>   said, I will dwell in them, and walk in them; and I will be their God,
>   and they shall be my people. (17)  **Wherefore come out from among them,
>   and be ye separate, saith the Lord,** and touch not the unclean thing;
>   and I will receive you, (18)  And will be a Father unto you, and ye
>   shall be my sons and daughters, saith the Lord Almighty.

Our faith should not be in the wisdom of men (the 666 group) but in the power of God.  The “princes of this world” are coming to nothing in their preaching of man’s wisdom.  They do not know Jesus Christ and Him crucified but are preaching other things in the wisdom of men.

> 1 Corinthians 2:1-8 KJV (1)  *And I, brethren, when I came to you, came
>   not with excellency of speech or of wisdom, declaring unto you the
>   testimony of God. (2)  For I determined not to know any thing among
>   you, save Jesus Christ, and him crucified. (3)  And I was with you in
>   weakness, and in fear, and in much trembling. (4)  And my speech and
>   my preaching was not with enticing words of man's wisdom, but in
>   demonstration of the Spirit and of power: (5)  **That your faith should
>   not stand in the wisdom of men, but in the power of God.** (6)  Howbeit
>   we speak wisdom among them that are perfect: yet not the wisdom of
>   this world, **nor of the princes of this world, that come to nought:** (7)
>   But we speak the wisdom of God in a mystery, even the hidden wisdom,
>   which God ordained before the world unto our glory:*

If they had known the Wisdom of God, they would not be crucifying the Lord of glory out of the lives of many as they neutralize the power of the cross in the authority/name of the beast.

> (8)  *Which none of the princes of this world knew: for had they known
>   it, **they would not have crucified the Lord of glory.***

Interestingly, there is a titlo (title mark) above chi xi in Papyrus 47 indicating this is a "sacred name".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very controversial issue. I'm going to share my *opinion*. The *six-hundred-sixty-six* (the number was written out, our digits were invented hundreds of years later in Pakistan) is symbolic. It is based on two symbols, three and six. Three symbolizes the Trinity. Six symbolizes man, whom God created on the sixth day.

The outward form is three of something, symbolizing divinity. However, the inward form is six, symbolizing man. Putting this together, this symbolizes a man acting as if he was a god.

One individual that fits the circumstances (tradition says that *The Revelation* was written in 95) was the emperor Domitian, who reigned from 79 to 96. Starting in 89, he became paranoid and had delusions of grandeur; contemporaries claimed that he insisted on the title, "Lord and God."

Again, this is just one theory out of many.

Comment: But this question isn't asking about the number, but the mark of the beast.